# Finding non-convex (or convac) hull in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Does OpenCV contain a non-convex hull function?

By non-convex hull I mean something like:
[image]

Comment: [like this?](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is convex hull, I asked for non-convex hull.

Comment: and then showed an example of convex hull... hence the question?

Comment: Sadly, no. But you can write (and share ;D) your own. I planned to implement this some time ago, but unfortunately I didn't found enough spare time... I'll let you know if I make some progress.

Comment: @GPPK He's referring to the red line, which is a "concave hull"

Comment: there is no universal solution because you your problem is ambiguous. you'll need some kind of heuristic to decide where the hull will be placed.

Comment: Seems you need `Alpha shapes` - for example - CGAL implementation http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you choose the concave hull like you did?
Concave hull isn't unique other than convex hull.

For example this is another concave hull (green):

[image]

You'll need some kind of heuristic to create a concave hull.

For example start with a delauny triangulation (can be computed with openCV afaik), find minimum, maximum and median edge length and choose to set a maximum edge length. Delete all edges longer than that. This assumes that your "object" samples are dense compared to non-object regions.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no non-convex hull function in OpenCV.

There is only [Convex hull](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html) but that doesn't really help.